# SWIG Interface File Structure Causing Duplicate Java Functions

Tags: swig

I have the below SWIG Interface file structure that I feel is invalid.  The int func(usigned char key[20]) resides in headerThree.h.  When I leave in the %include "HeaderThree.h" I get a duplicate int func(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char key);. If I remove the %include "HeaderThree.h", the other functions do not show up in the generated Example.java file..only the int func(short[] key) does.  I would like to configure the SWIG .i file to not have the 
func(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char key) function but to have the rest of the functions included in HeaderThree.h.  Any ideas?

```
%module Example
%{
#include "HeaderOne.h"  //has constants and type definitions
#include "HeaderTwo.h" // has an #include "HeaderOne.h" and its own C apis
#include "HeaderThree.h" // has an #include "HeaderOne.h" and its own C apis

%}
%include "arrays_java.i"
int func(unsigned char key[20]);
%include "HeaderOne.h" //has constants and type definitions
%include "HeaderTwo.h" // has an #include "HeaderOne.h" and its own C apis
%include "HeaderThree.h" // has an #include "HeaderOne.h" and its own C apis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you say `%include` it is as though you pasted the contents of the file directly at that point (i.e. asked SWIG to wrap it all).  This means SWIG has seen both versions of `func`, the one you explicitly told it about and the one that actually exists in the header you `%include`d.

There's a couple of ways you can fix this, although having the extra overload kicking around doesn't really do any harm, it's just noisy and messy.

1. Hide the declaration of `func` in the header file from SWIG using `#ifndef SWIG`. Your header file would then become:

   ```
   #ifndef SWIG
   int func(unsigned char *key);
   #endif
   ```

   When you `%include` that header file SWIG won't see this version of `func` - that's not a problem though because you explicitly told it about another version (which is compatible for the purposes of SWIG)
2. Use `%ignore` to instruct SWIG to ignore this version of `func` specifically. The SWIG module file then becomes:

   ```
   %module Example
   %{
   #include "HeaderOne.h"  
   #include "HeaderTwo.h" 
   #include "HeaderThree.h"
   %}

   %include "arrays_java.i"
   int func(unsigned char key[20]);
   // This ignore directive only applies to things seen after this point
   %ignore func; 
   %include "HeaderOne.h" 
   %include "HeaderTwo.h" 
   %include "HeaderThree.h"
   ```
3. You could also change the actual declaration and definition of `func` in the header file and the place it's actually implemented in your code to use `unsigned char[20]` instead of `unsigned char*`.

Comment: I used option #2 as we don't want to change the header files.  Thanks for all the options and the clear explanation!