# SWIG Configuration to Handle a FILE * C input Parameter in Java

Tags: java, swig

How would you configure the SWIG .i file to handle the C FILE * type?  The below function sets a file so that log output can be written to it. I need to call if from a Java class.  Currently a public static void setLogFile(SWIGTYPE_p_FILE fd) function is generated by SWIG when I just include the C header file with the below function.  Any ideas?

C Function:

```
void setLogFile(FILE *fd);
```

I attempted #1 using the below and got the below exception:

test.i:

```
%module Example
%{
#include "headerLogFile.h"
%}

%inline %{
void setLogFile(const char *fn) {
  FILE *f = fopen(fn, "w");
  setLogFile(f);
}
%}
%ignore setLogFile; 
%include "headerLogFile.h"
```

Exception:

```
[exec] test_wrap.c:193: error: conflicting types for 'setLogFile'
[exec] /test/include/headerLogFile.h:96: error: previous declaration of 'setLogFile' was here
[exec] test_wrap.c: In function `setLogFile':
[exec] test_wrap.c:195: warning: passing arg 1 of `setLogFile' from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given test.h which looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void setLogFile(FILE *fd) {
  fprintf(fd, "Test\n");
  fflush(fd);
}
```

I can see three approaches you might chose to take to wrapping this function:

### Method 1 - Pass a `String` from Java:

Expose a function to Java that expects a file name passed as a `String`, not a `FILE*`:

```
%module method1

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%inline %{
void setLogFile(const char *fn) {
  FILE *f = fopen(fn, "w");
  setLogFile(f);
}
%}
```

This uses `%inline` to instruct SWIG to wrap this function at the same time as defining it. If you still use `%include "test.h"` then you'd probably want to [hide the original version from SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320201/swig-interface-file-structure-causing-duplicate-java-functions/8323270#8323270).

---

### Method 2 - Wrap more of stdio.h:

Wrap more than just `setLogFile`, wrap things like `fopen`, `fmemopen` etc. as appropriate. (I don't like this solution much personally so I've not made an example for it)

---

### Method 3 - Expose a Java interface that takes a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html):

```
%module method3

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <cassert>
%}

// 3:
%typemap(jni) FILE *fd "jobject"
// 1:
%typemap(jstype) FILE *fd "java.io.FileOutputStream"
// 2:
%typemap(jtype) FILE *fd "java.io.FileDescriptor"
// 4:
%typemap(in) (FILE *fd) {
  jfieldID field_fd;
  jclass class_fdesc;
  int rawfd;
  class_fdesc = jenv->FindClass("java/io/FileDescriptor");
  assert(class_fdesc);
  field_fd = jenv->GetFieldID(class_fdesc, "fd", "I");
  assert(field_fd);
  rawfd = jenv->GetIntField($input, field_fd);
  $1 = fdopen(rawfd, "w");
  // Add some code to throw a Java exception if $1 is NULL (i.e. error)
}
// 5: 
%typemap(javain, pre="    retainFD = $javainput;",
         throws="java.io.IOException") FILE *fd "$javainput.getFD()"
// 6:
%pragma(java) modulecode=%{
  private static java.io.FileOutputStream retainFD;
%}

%include "test.h"
```

This does the following things:

1. We want the input to the actual public part of the module to be `java.io.FileOutputStream`.
2. The the Java side of the JNI code is going to take a `java.io.FileDescriptor` instead however.
3. The C++ side of the JNI code is going to see this as a `jobject`
4. On the C++ side we're going to do something that's a little evil - read a private `int` field in the `FileDescriptor` class ([see here](http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/jni-filedesc.html)). This is probably not portable and reading private parts of classes is generally considered bad, but it allows us to get something we can pass to `fdopen()` to get a `FILE*` for the "real" call
5. Mostly this typemap takes the `FileOutputStream` and calls `getFD()` on it to get the `FileDescriptor` object for it. It also adds an exception specification to match `getFD()` and performs one other function which is part of the next point
6. We need to be sure that Java won't garbage collect and finalize the `FileOutputStream`, which would close the file handle and invalidate our `FILE*`. We do this by keeping a reference to the `FileOutputStream` we were given in a `private static` variable. The `pre="...` of the previous typemap causes the most recent one to be retained until we change to another one. (If we do call `setLogFile` twice it's OK and in fact good that we release our reference to the previous `FileOutputStream`)

Comment: I tried #1 first and it seems like it still finds the other setLogFile function even though I attempt to hide it.  I updated the question with the exact SWIG file and exception if that helps...I have been able to hide other functions using the %ignore

Comment: @c12 - the problem there is you're doing something in C which would be an overload in C++, but C doesn't permit overloads. You probably want to give the `%inline` version of `setLogFile` a different name and then use either `%rename` with it or simply add some code on the Java side that forwards it to whatever the `%inline` version is now called.